# How to decorate a property to measure the time it executes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I tried to write a decorator to compute the time of the computation for methods in a class, but I also have a lot of properties.
I tried to write a decorator for a property as follows:

```
def timer(method):
    import time
    @property
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        start = time.time()
        result = method
        end = time.time()
        print('Elapsed time for: {} is: {}s'.format(method.__name__,(end-start)*1000))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

I can't get the name of the property as written, moreover perhaps you would suggest to write it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to stack decorators:

```
def timer(method):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)  # note the function call!
        end = time.time()
        print('Elapsed time for: {} is: {}s'.format(method.__name__,(end-start)*1000))
        return result
    return wrapper

class X:
    @property
    @timer
    def some_method(self):
        # timed code
        return 0

>>> x = X()
>>> x.some_method
Elapsed time for: some_method is: 0.0050067901611328125s
0
```

Comment: Does the stacking order matter? i.e. if it would be `@timer;@property;def some_method`?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the decorators. But yes, here and generally, it matters. `f(g(x))` is generally not the same as `g(f(x))`. Here, in particular the objects returned by the decorators are of different type. One returns a function, the other an Accessor.